# Text catecagorization for classifying gender from blog entries

Tags: text, categorization

I am researching on "text analysis".
Now I have a set of corpus, and I know gender of the author of each file.
So, how to build feature vectors for classifiers (bayes, SVM...). Or can you suggest some useful document for me about this topic? Thank you!